# Using case in vbScript

Tags: vbscript

I was working on a vbscript file that has a six element array.  The array is declared as follows.

```
dim grpaddarray(6), gpaddname

grpaddarray(0)= "someinformation"
grpaddarray(1)= "someinformation"
grpaddarray(2)= "someinformation"
grpaddarray(3)= "someinformation"
grpaddarray(4)= "someinformation"
grpaddarray(5)= "someinformation"
```

Being that I have them declared in lower case 'dim' instead of uppercase 'DIM' would my array objects be ignored when I call them.  I never used vbscript before so I did not know if case was a issue on the DIM.  Or should my program work the same with lower case or uppercase DIM, dim?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript is not case-sensitive, so `dim`, `DIM`, and `dIm` are all considered equivalent. Your array would still be an array.

(It seems to me you could have tested this in less time than you could have copied/pasted the code into this question.)

```
dim TestArray(3)
TestArray(0) = "Testing"
TestArray(1) = "Two"
TestArray(2) = 123

MsgBox TestArray(0)
MsgBox TestArray(1)
MsgBox TestArray(2)

DIM TestArrayTwo(3)
TestArrayTwo(0) = "Testing two"
TestArrayTwo(1) = "Two two"
TestArrayTwo(2) = 123456

MsgBox TestArrayTwo(0)
MsgBox TestArrayTwo(1)
MsgBox TestArrayTwo(2)
```

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right.  With this specific scenario I could not test it because I do not have access to the VM's that are scripted.  At the same time, I probably could have created my own personal test case so your right.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dim Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) article from MS uses a captialised version `Dim`. VBScript is not case sensitive so all three are valid. I would ensure I was always using the same case consistently within any codebase. For ease of typing `dim` saves a keystroke.